# Ruby on Rails associations - products provide and consume services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I'm relatively new to ruby on rails and I need some help to model the following scenario:

- The model contains Products and Services
- A Service must be provided by a Product (it cannot exist without a provider/owner)
- A Product can provide zero, one or many Services
- A Product can consume zero, one or many Services
- The provider (Product) can but is not automatically a consumer of the provided Service

Whats the best use of associations to be able to get:

- provided Services (from Product)
- consumed Services (from Product)
- consumers of the Service (from Service)
- the providing Product (from Service)

The problem is similar to this one [Many-to-many Users and groups, but groups have owners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442450/many-to-many-users-and-groups-but-groups-have-owners) (Users and Groups with Owner). But my Product is not necessarily a consumer of the provided Service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you

```
Service belongs_to :provider, class_name: "Product" # services has provider_id
Product has_many :provided_services, class_name: "Service", foreign_key: :provider_id

Product has_many :products_consumed_services
Product has_many :consumed_services, through: :products_consumed_services
ProductsConsumedService belongs_to :product
ProductsConsumedService belongs_to :consumed_service, class_name: "Service"

Service has_many :products_consumed_services, foreign_key: :consumed_service_id
Service has_many :consumers, through: :products_consumed_services, source: :product
```

**provided Services (from Product)**

```
product.provided_services
```

**consumed Services (from Product)**

```
product.consumed_services
```

**consumers of the Service (from Service)**

```
service.consumers
```

**providing Product (from Service)**

```
service.provider
```