# Rails 4 self referential many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't wrap my head around this any help would be appreciated. I went through many articles and other postings on here and I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for.

I have a User model and Team model.

Team Model has **user_id** and **team_id**

The user who creates the team will be user_id and users who are members of the team will be in the team_id

```
User Model
 has_many :teams, foreign_key: :team_id
 has_many :team_members, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: :user_id

Team Model
 belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :team_id    
 belongs_to :team_member, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
```

The end result of what I'm trying to achieve is:

- Each user can add as many team members
- Each user can see a list of users who are part of their team.
- A view where, Users who are part of a team can see which team they are part of.

Comment: I suspect you want a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) relationship, but it's not entirely clear what you're wanting to do.

Comment: @Undo thanks for commenting. I looked into that but couldn't get it to work. Can you show me an example how I would use it within the model i have above?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is a [join table model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). The issue is that both a `User` and a `Team` may have many of each other. So the relationship must be stored separately.

See this answer here on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442583/5113832

So you might choose a model structure of `User`, `Team` and `TeamMembership`.

**Updated** to destroy dependent team memberships when a user or team is destroyed.

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_memberships
end

#app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :team_memberships
end

#app/models/team_membership.rb
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

**Updated** to reply to question:

> How would my controller look on create? (Adding a user to a team) – Michael

In order to add a user to to a team you COULD do it in `UserController`, you COULD do it in `TeamController`. However, because you are now creating a `TeamMembership` resource you would want to create a `TeamMembership` record in a `TeamMembershipsController`. This keeps with the "Rails" way of doing things. So for example:

```
# app/controllers/team_memberships_controller.rb
class TeamMembershipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @team_memberships = TeamMembership.all
  end

  def new
    @team_membership = TeamMembership.new
  end

  def create
    @team_membership = TeamMembership.new(team_membership_params)
    if @team_membership.save
      flash[:success] = 'Team membership created'
      redirect_to team_memberships_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Team membership not created'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @team_membership = TeamMembership.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @team_membership && @team_membership.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Team membership destroyed'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Team membership not destroyed'
    end
    redirect_to team_memberships_path
  end


  private
  def team_membership_params
    params.require(:team_membership).permit(
      :user_id,
      :team_id
    )
  end
end
```

The advantage to having the `TeamMembership` resource is using this pattern to manage when a user is added (#create), or removed (#destroy) from a team.

The magic of Rails [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) will take care of accessing a team's members (users) and a user's teams for each instance of those models.

You just go about your business doing [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) on these resources and Rails takes care of the organization for you by your conforming to it's conventions.

Also I updated my original model code to destroy team memberships when a user or team is destroyed. This ensures no [orphaned records](http://www.dhdursoassociates.com/database-glossary-3.html#orphan) are in your `team_memberships` table.

As a final note. You should also be able to easily use `form_for` to send a `TeamMembership` to your controller to be created. This could be done using select option dropdowns for users and teams with Rails' [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select):

```
<%# app/views/team_memberships/new.html.erb %>
<h1>
  Create Team Membership
</h1>

<%= form_for(@team_membership) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label(:user) %>
  <%= f.collection_select(
    :user_id,
    User.all,
    :id,
    :username
  ) %>

  <%= f.label(:team) %>
  <%= f.collection_select(
    :team_id,
    Team.all,
    :id,
    :name
  ) %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above code will render dropdown for all users and teams allowing you to select a specific combination to create a team membership from. Deleting a team membership is as easy as sending a `DELETE #destroy` request with the `id` of the team membership.

Another consideration might be adding a [unique pair constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923796/how-do-you-validate-uniqueness-of-a-pair-of-ids-in-ruby-on-rails) to your database table and model within the migration and model validations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this makes sense! How would my controller look on create? (Adding a user to a team)

Comment: If you have a user like `user = User.first` and a team `team = Team.first` you can add the user to the team by using `team.users << user` and calling `team.save`

Comment: @Michael I updated my answer to give an example of how a TeamMembershipsController would look as well as some views, forms and tips.